# Dojo dGrid/dStore realtime update

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, dgrid, dstore

I've been trying to get my dgrid/dstore grid in realtime.
As var as I understand the function 'Observable' is deprecated, and also it doesnt work for me.

I've tried to update the grid via a Interval timer but then the whole grid is erased and new loaded. How to update the whole grid 'inline' without erasing, and showing 'loading data'?

This is my basic code:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  store.invalidate(); // Invalidate the cache
  store.fetch(); // Perform a new request for all items
  grid.refresh(); 
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 5):

Observable does not exist in dstore, but there is a [`Trackable`](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Stores.md#trackable) mixin which can be used instead. As for updating the grid when new content is fetch from the store, you could use a `dstore/Cache` and then pass the cached `Memory` store that mixes in `Trackable` to the grid to use instead. Each time new data is added to the caching store, it will also be reflected in the grid.

```
require([
    'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
    'dstore/Rest',
    'dstore/Memory',
    'dstore/Trackable',
    'dstore/Cache',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function (OnDemandGrid, Rest, Memory, Trackable, Cache) {
    var restStore = new Rest({
        target: '/mockRequest/'
    });

    var store = Cache.create(restStore, {
        cachingStore: new (Memory.createSubclass(Trackable))()
    });

    var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
        collection: store.cachingStore,
        columns: {
            id: 'ID',
            name: 'Name',
            description: 'Description'
        },
        loadingMessage: 'Loading...'
    }, 'main');
    grid.startup();

    setInterval(function () {
        store.fetch();
    }, 2000);
});
```